# If a webserver has a host name and a different alias DNS name, what will be the value of document.domain?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain-policy

I have a webserver with the following host name and DNS alias name.

```
Host name - server1.aa.xx.company.com
Alias name - server1.bb.xx.company.com
```

In the above scenario, what will be the value of JavaScript DOM object document.domain? Will it be **server1.aa.xx.company.com** or will it be **server1.bb.xx.company.com**?

Answer (score 2):

> what will be the value of JavaScript DOM object document.domain

It will be the domain the page was requested in the browser on. Javascript isn't interested in DNS aliases - just in what it says in the browser's address bar.